# Creating charts in Google Spreadsheet - Mutiple Sheets

Tags: google-chrome, google-docs

I have Google sheet to maintain Home income and expense. See the link below, in this I gave sample data etc.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iH5swIP6HiyqfRhrOS-1LxzeNeFeosd4rXOMx6I1uiI/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to create a chart using all the sheets on the spreadsheet. How do I do that? This is basically Home income and expense sheets. Please help me to create chart.

Comment: The question is too broad, and if it doesn't have anything to do with programming, then it's really a question about basic usage.  Providing a link to the spreadsheet with information in it is very good, but learning how to insert a chart literally takes only a few seconds.  In the time you took to post this, you could have highlighted some data, and choose Insert - Chart.

Comment: I did it is giving me an error 'All the series on a given axis must of same data type'

Comment: anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: I am able to get all the data into one sheet, but still having trouble creating chart. See the 'Chart' tab in the link.

Comment: It states that negative values are invalid for a pie chart.  You'll need to restructure how you record the values, or maybe convert the negative value to a positive.  Maybe [ABS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093459)

Comment: If I convert, how do I show income and expense?